# How to add stylesheet select options in slightly modded options framework

Tags: wordpress

I can not add functions which will add a select options where I will able to select my stylesheet.

Suppose, I have 3 stylesheet (red.css, blue.css and green.css). Now I want to add a functions in SMOF where I will able to select stylesheet and my WordPress site's design will change according to stylesheet.

My codes are below-

```
//Stylesheets Reader
        $alt_stylesheet_path = LAYOUT_PATH;
        $alt_stylesheets = array();

        if ( is_dir($alt_stylesheet_path) )
        {
            if ($alt_stylesheet_dir = opendir($alt_stylesheet_path) )
            {
                while ( ($alt_stylesheet_file = readdir($alt_stylesheet_dir)) !== false )
                {
                    if(stristr($alt_stylesheet_file, ".css") !== false)
                    {
                        $alt_stylesheets[] = $alt_stylesheet_file;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and

```
$of_options_select  = array("option 1","option 2","option 3");              
$of_options[] = array(  "name"      => "Logo Uploader",
                        "desc"      => "Upload logo",
                        "id"        => "logo",
                        "std"       => "three",
                        "type"      => "select",
                        "options"   => $of_options_select
                );
```

Anyone please help me. I want this select functions in my WordPress theme.

Comment: This should be moved to [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get these options in your theme
Here is the link where you can find how to use these option in your wordpress theme
http://aquagraphite.com/2011/11/smof-documentation/

Example:
New input text field to be added in the option panel
id (attribute) should be unique because you will access your data by this id.

```
$of_options[] = array(  "name"      => "Site Title",
                        "desc"      => "",
                        "id"        => "ams_site_title",
                        "std"       => "My Site",
                        "type"      => "text"
                );
```

Access the data in your theme files by globalizing the $data array and use your id of input.

```
global $data; //fetch options stored in $data
echo $data['ams_site_title'];
```

That's it.